# Touch move getting stuck after 30-80 times & in console error is coming

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-touch-punch

Full Error:

```
[Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
preventDefault  @   jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   number_grid_game.php:239
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   number_grid_game.php:234
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:2
y.handle    @   jquery.min.js:2
```

I have a code where touch events are used. When I start dragging, at first 10-30 steps it's normal but after 30-35 steps it's drag become slow & struggle to drag. I'm not sure what is causing this problem, I am new to working with touch events and can't seem to fix this problem.
Here is the code handling the touch event:

```
$(window)
.on('touchstart', function(event) {
    var missingNumbers, $target = $(event.target);

   if(!$target.hasClass('missing-number'))
        return;
    missingNumbers = MissingNumbers.ByElement($target);
    //185
    $.each(event.originalEvent.changedTouches, function(index, touch) {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        missingNumbers.startDrag($target, touch.identifier, touch.pageX, touch.pageY);
    });
})

.on('touchmove', function(event) {
    $.each(event.originalEvent.changedTouches, function(index, touch) {
        var touchId = touch.identifier;

       if((touchId in MissingNumbers.DraggedElements)) {

            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            MissingNumbers.DoCellDrag(touchId, touch.pageX, touch.pageY);
        }
    });
})

.on('touchend', function(event) {

    $.each(event.originalEvent.changedTouches, function(index, touch) {
        var touchId = touch.identifier;
        if((touchId in MissingNumbers.DraggedElements)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            MissingNumbers.EndCellDrag(touchId);
        }
    });

});
```

any solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got the solution..
put css = 'touch-action:none' to the div area & everything will work fine.

Comment: Solved it for me! Thanks